# All-in-one PHP solution to share files?

Tags: php, bittorrent

I have enough hard-disk space on a PHP-capable hosted site so I can host the files there instead of my work PC at home.

I was wondering if someone knew of a good, light PHP server application that supports the BitTorrent protocol and run a tracker, so I could simply make the .torrent file available and customers would download from the server without depending on third-parties (trackers like OpenBitTorrent, search engines like MiniNova, etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: for files with limited appeal, what is the benefit over direct downloads (ftp/http/etc)? Essentially you will be a cloud of one, and the client might not have a torrent application (an extra layer of complexity).

Comment: Just in case I need to share big files, and learn how to use BitTorrent.

Comment: The learning part is one thing, but to share big files, the advantage of BT is for you to have other people do the serving for you. If your clients are not seeding, then you are serving them in the same fashion as ftp etc.

Comment: Yes I know, but I wanted to learn what the options were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many well known sites use one of the following:

- [TBsource](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tbsource/)
- [PHPBTTracker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpbttrkplus/)

Answer (score 2):

It's not pure PHP, but check out what.cd's Gazelle. It runs some of the most mature private trackers out there. However, I'm not sure where to find it. I've used [PHPBTTracker](http://phpbttrkplus.sourceforge.net/) before, and it did the trick, though it was annoying to configure. Check out the [tracker comparison on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_tracker_software) for more info on software to fill this niche.